# Laravel 5.1 pass data from view to modal

Tags: laravel-5.1, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

How can I pass data from blade view to modal dialog :
For example : 
I pass $user from controller to view :

```
 $user = User::findOrFail($id);
 return view('user.show')->withUser($user);
```

Next, I want to pass this data $user to a modal included in this view via a button like this :

`@include('user.edit',$user)`;

and there in the modal I can set $user's values (like this : {!! $user->lastname !!} ) to edit them for example.

Please Help me :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try out this way. I am using `a` tag, but the solution should work for you as well with button.

```
<a
    href="#"
    data-target="yourModalId"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-email="{{ $user->email }}"
    data-username="{{ $user->username }}"
 >
     Edit
</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#yourModalId').on('show', function(e) {
    var link     = e.relatedTarget(),
        modal    = $(this),
        username = link.data("username"),
        email    = link.data("email");

    modal.find("#email").val(email);
    modal.find("#username").val(username);
});
```

Create the input fields inside the modal window with the `id` that are passed in `find` method.

That will put the values passed in the input fields inside modal window..

Comment: Great !!! Thanks a lot for you help ! 
but there's still a problem : how could I validate fields before sending them to update method in controller ? because here if I press submit button without filling required fields (should get errors and stay on modal with old values) the Modal hides and the $user doesn't update :/

Comment: Any tutorial about validating modal by Ajax ? thanks :)

Comment: Not sure but laracasts should help you out with what you are looking for.. Or simply google: laravel ajax validation

Comment: May be this can give you an idea... Check it out... https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/showing-request-validation-errors-when-submitting-form-by-ajax

Answer (score 2):

You can use the blade [include()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures) function, which accepts an array as the second parameter:

`@include('user.edit', ['user' => $user])`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I can't resend $user from view to modal by this code ! this is work for defined value for example : 

@include(('user.edit', ['user' => 'value'])

But I want to resend the hole user passed in view via controller, and in modal I can retrieve user's data like this : {!! $user->username !!}

Comment: you are wrong, the code I gave you is working, the user.edit view will have the all $user data

Comment: sorry but how could you set your code to send $user ? 
once you pass $user to view, you can just retrieve its fields, so if you tried it please set a code to follow you :)

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding from me,what you really asking is: how to pass data from js to php?