# Pass data to modal in the same page, Laravel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

So i have this index page which has the list of task and inside the table is the title of task and the actions, what i'm trying to do is when i click the task title the modal will pop whereas in the modal is its body and content of the said task.. here is the code

controller

```
public function index()
{   
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

index page

```
  @extends('layout.app')
  @section('content')
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="float:left;">
        <h2>Todo List</h2>
        <div class="table-hover">
          <table class="table">
          <thead class="thead-default">
          <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           @if(count($todos) > 0)
            @foreach($todos as $todo)
            <tr>
                <th><a href="/todo/{{$todo->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal3">{{$todo->title}}</a></th>
                <td>{{$todo->status}}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-sample btn-sm">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-sample2 btn-sm">Delete<a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
            @endforeach
                @else
                <th><h2>Nothing to show</h2></th>
            @endif
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the modal below the same page

```
                                                                         <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModal3Label" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModal3Label">View task</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
       </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>{{$todo->title}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can extract the code of your modal to a partial and then include it with passing the variable o it like this : `@include('partials.modal', ['todo'=>$todo])` !

Comment: @Maraboc it is going to add a modal for every todo. I think better would create a one modal and change their content

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473015/laravel-5-1-pass-data-from-view-to-modal) :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to achieve this, either you repeat your modal with unique `id` with `tr` or records, or you create one modal, and `onClick` bring data from `ajax` or `javascript`, and fill it within modal.
I'm explaining you the first and easiest one

```
  @extends('layout.app')
  @section('content')
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="float:left;">
        <h2>Todo List</h2>
        <div class="table-hover">
          <table class="table">
          <thead class="thead-default">
          <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           @if(count($todos) > 0)
            @foreach($todos as $todo)
            <tr>
                <th><a href="/todo/{{$todo->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{ $loop->iteration }}.">{{$todo->title}}</a>
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModal3Label{{ $loop->iteration }}">View task</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                           </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                            <h3>{{$todo->title}}</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                </th>
                <td>{{$todo->status}}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-sample btn-sm">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-sample2 btn-sm">Delete<a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
            @endforeach
                @else
                <th><h2>Nothing to show</h2></th>
            @endif
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```