# Using jQuery How can I find a distant parent element with few(er) parent() instances

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class to an element outside the ancestry. The following method does the task, however I'd like to lessen the use of `parent()` instances.

**The code**

```
<h4 class="tab">Title</h4>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><p class="send">add class to h4 from here</p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".send").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().prev().addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

**I tried**

All the following efforts fail to return the desired result.

```
$(".send").closest(".tab").addClass("active");
```

---

```
$(".send").find(".tab").addClass("active");
```

#### Update for clarity

The method is used for a slide down accordion where items are selected by the client, and each tab is highlighted if there are item(s) chosen. **Also I have no control over the elements** so I cannot add or remove classnames, and the structure is exactly as shown. I am just adding this method as a dynamic modification of the extension.

[image]

Comment: May I ask why you can't just use `$(".tab")`

Comment: Can't you add a global container for the selection?

Comment: I assume you are trying to create some sort of edit modal where in data is grabbed dynamically from the dom, in that case my answer to a similar requirement should help, note that it is for a table but the same concepts still apply. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48863079/2757519

Comment: @fortunee the sending element only adds the class on a user action. I just did not include all the other coding that shows the whole process. It is quite long. Hence the reason I can't just use `$('.tab')`

Comment: Does this HTML will be repeated?

Comment: @Ainz-sama it is a slide accordion or drop down, and within each container, the user initiates an action with the `.send` element and the tab should receive the class to indicate that it is active, so the user is not guessing which closed slide was used.

Comment: @Bhautik yes the HTML is repeated numerous times and only the <h4> and inner <li> content changes. All the element classes remain constant.

Comment: @mchev I don't see how a global container would resolve the case.

Comment: Can you update HTML as well with repeat?t

Comment: @Bhautik no I cannot alter the HTML, it's a third party extension and I am just adding a method to create alerts. Please see the updates in my original post for some clarity.

Comment: But you can inspect that HTML and you can see how it's rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you can't assign a unique class:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".send").parents().find('.tab').addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h4 class="tab">Title</h4>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><p class="send">add class to h4 from here</p></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This jQuery method returns all parents. Please read the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Comment: This method does add the class, however it finds all elements with `h4.tab` and add, which defeats the goal. However it presents a concept to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making your life so hard? Just give the element you want to access a dummy class (or even ID if it’s unique) so you can easily access it with $(‚.dummyclass‘) ?